# how to build openPose in QT Project?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake-gui, openpose

I'm Student, in Korea.
um..sorry about that I am not good in English.

so I used translate program KOR to ENG.

I succeed test opnePose demo.

I want to build openPose GUI Program.

But, I can't build project openPose with QT.

Cannot find with_qt in cmake-gui.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Avd.png)

how to build openPose project with QT?

Help me please..I stayed up three nights...

I want to complete this project.

*Development Environment

- Win 10 64 Pro
- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- CMake 3.13.3
- Openpose 1.4.0
- CUDA 8.0.61 win 10
- Cudnn 8.0 win 10 64 v5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is how to enable QT in the OpenCV that openpose uses. You are looking for a WITH_QT option as you saw in OpenCV, but one is not present in OpenPose.

This is because openpose does not come with opencv, but will use the opencv that you provide it. If you have built opencv with Qt, provide that version to openpose by setting the OpenCV_DIR to the path of your OpenCV install.

Comment: Thank you jhauris!